# skip elements in each function by conditions

Tags: jquery

how can I skip some elements in `each` function of jquery by the next condition:

```
var number_of_td = 0;
$('td').each(function() {
    if (number_of_td == 0) {
       if ($(this).attr('id') == "1") {
           //skip the next three elements:
           //something like: $(this) = $(this).next().next().next();
        }
    }
    else if (number_of_td == 1) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "2") {
           //skip the next two elements
        }
    }
    else if (number_of_td == 2) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "3") {
           //skip the next element
        }
    }
    else if (number_of_td == 3) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "4") {
           //skip the next element
        }
    }
    else {
        number_of_td++;
        if (number_of_td == 4) {
             number_of_td = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

for example:

```
<td attr="1"></td>
<td attr="6"></td>
<td attr="7"></td>
<td attr="9"></td>
//-------------------
<td attr="2"></td>
<td attr="5"></td>
<td attr="3"></td>
<td attr="6"></td>
//-------------------
<td attr="7"></td>
<td attr="2"></td>
<td attr="8"></td>
<td attr="6"></td>
```

if one of the 4th conditions exists, skip till the td element with `attr=2`.

in this example, the first td attribute is 1, so it skips till attr=2 and not check the other elements (attr=6,7,9).

2 is not equal to 1, 5 is not equal to 2, 3 is equal to 3, so it skips till attr=7, etc.

I hope you can understand my example.

any help appreciated!

Comment: .filter(...) http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: your jQuery is looking for an id (`$(this).attr('id')`) but your td elements don't have an id.  Plus, why are you using the `each` function?

Comment: What are you attempting to do overall?  Your example doesn't make much sense from a programming standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a counter variable, and skip the loop if the counter hasn't reached zero:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    if (+$(this).data('counter')>0) { 
        $(this).data('counter', $(this).data('counter')-1); // decrement counter
        return; // continue to next loop iteration
    }
    if (number_of_td == 0) {
       if ($(this).attr('id') == "1") {
           $(this).data('counter', 2); // skip two more after this one
           return; // skip to next loop iteration
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a small note: `.attr('id')` should be `.attr('attr')` if you look at OP's code. I don't think he's using id:s, since there are multiple occurences of the same values.

Comment: @Johan  I thought it reasonable to assume his JavaScript was accurate, but his HTML was a pared-down (mis)representation.